# Mapping inheritance with fluent nhibernate seems a bit off

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

A part of my Model looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public virtual int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Partner { get; set; }
}
```

The generated sql for this is:

```
create table [Person] (
   Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
   Name NVARCHAR(255) null,
   Employee_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER null,
   primary key (Id)
)

create table Employee (
   Person_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
   EmployeeNumber INT null,
   Partner_Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER null,
   primary key (Person_id)
)
```

Why is there a `Employee_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER null,` inside the Person table?

Comment: What does your mapping look like?

Comment: @Andrew Withaker; the mapping is done using the automapping feature of FluentNhibernate.

Comment: @Mr Happy - see http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_configuration#Exporting_mappings for instructions on generating *.hbm.xml files based on FluentNHibernate's automappings.  Viewing these files is the logical next step in diagnosing this issue.  Please post the relevant resulting *.hbm.xml files here, and we will try to help you figure out what's going on.  Also, do you have any pertinent IAutoMappingOverride classes?  Conventions?  An AutomappingConfiguration class?